# Is it possible to process Event Bus's events only by a single top activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, event-bus

When we use an event bus (from Guava) to fetch async responses from server - everything works absolutely correctly. But if we want to to open another instance of the same activity on top, then our Subscribe-events will be processed also in the bottom (stopped) activity what causes different sources of bugs.

Is it possible to make event bus's events to be processed only by a single subscriber from the current top activity?

Comment: Yes, you can do it.
Unregister the activity from EventBus in onPause() method. Only top one visible activity will be register.

Comment: Then I will lose all server responses in event bus obtained while activity is being stopped.

Comment: You can post sticky event which will wait till handle once.

Comment: I think this can solve my problem, but I don't know only about one exception. In the current case, when my activity is being closed (when we exactly close it, not when it's a kind of screen orientation change) we don't process subscribed events in it - it's a correct behavior for me. But when we will use sticky events, we will obtain the last event after activity will be opened again, right?

Comment: The sticky event doesn't get destroyed till someone handle them or application got killed.
When you move to foreground from background or change orientation the first register activity for that event will get the callback.

Comment: I understand this, it is quite logical. But I want to make event be lost when the activity is being closed. I don't want to save sticky event, if it was posted after activity's death (not only after screen orientation change).

Comment: Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove all the sticky event when you activity re-creates on just before destroy using:-

```
stickyEvent= EventBus.getDefault().getStickyEvent(classType);
// Better check that an event was actually posted before
        if(stickyEvent != null) {
            // "Consume" the sticky event
            EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(stickyEvent);
        }
```

Comment: I think that your idea to use sticky events has led me to the complete solution of my problem, so I think it will be correct from me to accept your answer. However, I want to sum up everything we've discussed and post as a separate answer to provide a kind of boilerplate for users with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

## There are two workarounds to do that:

1. Where you are subscribing for and event just before the subscribing do unsubscribe first and then subscribe. Following this will do only one subscription at a time in eventbus event stack.
2. I think you have a BaseActivity, And whenever you create one the eventbus subscription occurs on every activity. For this you can subscribe in onresume and unsubscribe in onpause will make your problem solved.

Comment: Can you provide some comment about the first one, please? I didn't get the idea.

Comment: the idea is that for one activity if the subscriber has to be attached only once and you are subscribing within a block which is called more than once then you have to unsubscribe before subscription to have only one callback when the event is published

Comment: Ok, thank you. But one more question then: how can we be sure that the correct instance of the activity was subscribed, not the one in the currently stopped case?

Comment: That is confirmed because the only the resumed activity i.e. the activity in front is subscribed and the paused is already unsubscribed

Answer (score 2):

For those who used to exploit event bus paradigm to fetch results of async actions (and keep activity's or fragment's orientation change events and correct work even if we have multiple same activities currently opened), I suggest the following boilerplate implementation. It's based on the Greenrobot's event bus library, but of course it's not difficult to use any other libraries here.

First of all, let's create a kind of helper class to send events for event bus:

```
/**
 * Helps to send sticky events avoiding them to be sent when the current screen (content entity)
 * is about to be closed.
 */
public enum EventBusHelper {

/** Single instance. */
INSTANCE;

/**
 * Posts sticky event to make activity fetch it (if activity is not finishing).
 *
 * @param activity An activity to check state.
 * @param event    An event to be fired.
 * */
public void postStickyIfNotFinishing(@NonNull Activity activity, Object event) {
    postStickyIfNotFinishing(activity.isFinishing(), event);
}

/**
 * Posts sticky event to make fragment fetch it (if fragment is not finishing).
 *
 * @param fragment A fragment to check state.
 * @param event    An event to be fired.
 * */
public void postStickyIfNotFinishing(@NonNull Fragment fragment, Object event) {
    postStickyIfNotFinishing(fragment.isRemoving(), event);
}

/**
 * Posts sticky event if a subscriber is not going to be finished.
 *
 * @param isFinishing True - if subscriber will be finished.
 * @param event An event to be sent.
 * */
private void postStickyIfNotFinishing(boolean isFinishing, Object event) {
    if (!isFinishing)
        EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(event);
}
```

The main purpose of this class is to send events for Subscribe-methods only if our activity, fragment (dialog fragment) is not going to be closed. Otherwise we'll get an unacceptable behavior, when we're getting some instant data on the next launch of the activity (fragment, etc) without firing our request first. But this event sending methods don't block sending of the event, when our screen entity (activity, fragment) is about to be recreated after the change of screen's orientation.

The next step - is to register and unregister event bus on start and stop actions of our activity or fragment:

```
/**
 * Initializing event bus to process completed tasks.
 * */
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

/**
 * Stopping event bus to avoid background ops processing.
 * */
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

It's necessary for two purposes:

1. To avoid any background actions, when we receive a callback of our background task.
2. To avoid processing of our callback for multiple screen entities (activities, etc) when they are opened at the same time (one activity is on top of another one). It works, because the only one screen entity is currently active on our screen (another one is in stopped state).

And the last step. When we want to post some event in our fragment or activity (after obtaining the response from async server request for example), we should use post methods from our helper class:

```
ExampleAsyncRequest exampleAsyncRequest = new ExampleAsyncRequest(
            new Response.Listener<ExampleAsyncRequestResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(ExampleAsyncRequestResponse response) {
                    EventBusHelper.INSTANCE.postStickyIfNotFinishing(OurFragment.this, response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(ExampleAsyncRequestError error) {
                    EventBusHelper.INSTANCE.postStickyIfNotFinishing(OurFragment.this, error);
                }
    });
```

And to fetch these events in our bus we use the next code:

```
@Subscribe(sticky = true)
public void onExampleAsyncRequestResponse(ExampleAsyncRequestResponse response) {
    EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(response);
    ...
}

@Subscribe(sticky = true)
public void onExampleAsyncRequestError(ExampleAsyncRequestError error) {
    EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(error);
    ...
}
```

We have to remove obtained sticky events to avoid them to be processed by another activity or fragment which is currently under the top one.

Comment: nice, you have posted a complete answer with combining all the comments.